# Using android's tables and triggers in my application - licence

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a question about licenses.

In my app I want to use the same database **structure** and **triggers** as is in normal android app (mmssms.db).

Can I do it and copy them? I assume that my new application will be paid.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can. There is no relation between your app license & it's db structure/triggers.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. However android's developers have created this structures and triggers and it works in the normal default sms app. It is certainly not an infringement of copyright ? In particular, use the same code (copy it to my own application) which it is in triggers? Maybe I should change something or on the basis of this structure to do new (similar)

Comment: to my best knowledge, they don't fall under copyright infringement. but you shouldn't directly copy/paste their code.